# Style ImageView in Android

Tags: android

How to change the `ImageView` slowly with style

For example, an image of a Cat in the screen, then the image becomes darker then disappears and a new image of another Cat replaces for the previous image. And after a duration of time, the `ImageView` will be changed again and again ..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a custom Drawabe class that in Drawable.draw() method draws two Bitmaps: one fading out and the other fading in, or use TransitionDrawable

Comment: You want an animation, to transition from one view to another. There are several ways to do this.

Comment: You can try to use : setColorFilter(int color). Increment the int for darker effect. If you want that image disappear, modify setAlpha(int alpha). You can also read the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score -1):

First You need to Create A Folder in res like
res/animation

Then Create a `xml` named as `translate.xml`

Copy this code to it

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/res/apk/android"
android:duration="4000"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fillEnabled="false"
android:fromXDelta="200"
android:fromYDelta="200"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:startOffset="1000"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="0" >
```

```
Then To use This Style 
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.animation.translate);



imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Thanks , it will Work ....

And You can change time in the above `xml` in `android:duration="4000"` accordingly